# Simple Safe for Loading and Retrieving Digital Images

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, sqlite

I wrote this little utility program that saves and load digital images such as videos, pictures among others in a database. I used `click` module for it's interface. Am fairly new to `click` and `sqlite` module. I would love to enhance and improve this project and would love to get feedbacks concerning what I have done so far.

### user.py

```
class User():
    
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.username = name 
        self.password = password
```

### dbcon.py

```
import os
import sqlite3

class DBCon:
    """Database connection state"""

    def __init__(self, path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'safe_db.sqlite3')):
        self.path = path    
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
        self.cursor = None

    def create_tables(self, con):
        """Create sqlite3 tables"""

        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        try:
            users = """
            CREATE TABLE users(
                username text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                password text NOT NULL
            )"""
            images = """
            CREATE TABLE images(
                id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                image BLOB NOT NULL,
                filename text NOT NULL,
                username text,
                FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)
            )"""
            self.cursor.execute(users)
            self.cursor.execute(images)
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            return self.cursor

        return self.cursor

    def drop_tables(self):
        drop_users = """DROP TABLE users"""
        drop_images = """DROP TABLE images"""
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute(drop_users)
        self.cursor.execute(drop_images)
        print('Dropped all tables sucessfully')
```

### safe.py

```
import click

from user import User
from dbcon import DBCon

@click.group(chain=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    """This program saves and loads image files to a database.
        Please initialize the database using 'initdb' before using the program.
    """
    ctx.obj = DBCon()

def to_binary(filename):
    """Convert a digital data to binary data"""

    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        blob_data = fp.read()

    return blob_data

def to_digital(data, filename):
    """Convert binary data to digital"""

    with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(data)
    print('Stored digital data into: {}'.format(filename))


def auth(dbcon, username, password):
    user_query = """SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1"""
    dbcon.cursor.execute(user_query, (username,))
    record = dbcon.cursor.fetchone()
    if record[1] != password:
        click.echo('Invalid Username and/or Password')
        return None

    return record

@cli.command(short_help='Initialize the database')
@click.pass_obj
def initdb(ctx):
    ctx.cursor = ctx.create_tables(ctx.connection)

@cli.command(short_help='Drop the database')
@click.pass_obj
def dropdb(ctx):
    ctx.drop_tables()

@cli.command(short_help='Create a new user')
@click.argument('username', metavar='<username>')
@click.argument('password', metavar='<password>')
@click.pass_obj
def createuser(ctx, username, password):
    u = User(username, password)
    insert_query = """INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)"""
    ctx.cursor = ctx.connection.cursor()
    ctx.cursor.execute(insert_query, (u.username, u.password))
    ctx.connection.commit()
    
    return u

@cli.command(short_help='Insert image into database')
@click.argument('username', metavar='<username>')
@click.argument('path_to_image', metavar='<Path_to_image_file>')
@click.password_option(prompt=True)
@click.pass_obj
def insertdata(ctx, username, path_to_image, password):
    ctx.cursor = ctx.connection.cursor()
    user_record = auth(ctx, username, password)
    if user_record:
        insert_query = """INSERT INTO images(image, username, filename) VALUES (?, (SELECT username from users WHERE username=?), ?)"""
        image = to_binary(path_to_image)
        ctx.cursor.execute(insert_query, (image, username, path_to_image))
    ctx.connection.commit()

@cli.command(short_help='Get image from database')
@click.argument('username', metavar='<username>')
@click.argument('path_to_image', metavar='<Path_to_image_file>')
@click.password_option(prompt=True)
@click.pass_obj
def getdata(ctx, username, path_to_image, password):
    record = None
    ctx.cursor = ctx.connection.cursor()
    user_record = auth(ctx, username, password)
    if user_record:
        select_query = """SELECT image from images WHERE username = ? AND filename=? LIMIT 1"""
        ctx.cursor.execute(select_query, (username, path_to_image))
        record = ctx.cursor.fetchone()
        if record:
            image_path = path_to_image
            to_digital(record[0], image_path)
        else:
            click.echo('No such data in database')

@cli.command(short_help="List all images in the database")
@click.argument('username', metavar='<username>')
@click.password_option()
@click.pass_obj
def li(ctx, username, password): # li is equivalent to listimages
    ctx.cursor = ctx.connection.cursor()
    user_record = auth(ctx, username, password)
    records= None
    if user_record:
        select_query = """SELECT filename FROM images WHERE username = ?"""
        ctx.cursor.execute(select_query, (username,))
        records = ctx.cursor.fetchall()

        for record in records:
            click.echo(record[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

For installation purposes, I also included a setup file

### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='safe',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['safe'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points ='''
        [console_scripts]
        safe=safe:cli
    ''',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job overall. When running your code through a linter I haven't got too many issues which is a great first step to begin with!

- `User()` shouldn't be a class. You don't even need variables for `username` and `password` since they're going to be introduced by the user anyway + you're not using them anywhere else but in `createuser` function.
- Don't write raw queries. Use an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It'll save you from writing a lot of boilerplate code and it also adds an extra security layer. Another advantage is the relative ease with which you can handle changes to the database structure + many others.
- In `create_tables`, whatever happens you return the `cursor`. Wouldn't you want instead to raise an exception if something doesn't work?
- `successfully` instead of `sucessfully`
- `if record[1] != password:` this will raise an `IndexError` exception if there's no record. I'd first check `if record: ...`
- `return None` is the same as `return`
- **DON'T store plain-text credentials in DB.** You can check the [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) library for this purpose.
- `def li(ctx, username, password):  # li is equivalent to listimages` -> why write a comment instead of just naming your function `list_images(...)`?
- `records = None` & `record = None` have no purpose whatsoever.
- in `setup.py` try to specify the [Python versions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#classifiers) you support in your project

Comment: Would `sqlalchemy` add overhead?

Comment: IMO, if used correctly, no, it doesn't. Technically speaking, at the ORM level, the speed issues might appear because creating objects in Python is slow, and the SQLAlchemy ORM applies a large amount of bookkeeping to these objects as it fetches them, which is necessary in order for it to fulfill its usage contract, including unit of work, identity map, eager loading, collections, etc.

Comment: I would stick to raw `sql` for now, if issues arises, I would port to `sqlalchemy` . I really don't want to add too many complex stuff since the project is still minimal